# Can a reduction and GOTO be in one state in LR Parsing?

Tags: parsing, syntax, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, lr-grammar

In the below example, it's clear that when you want to go in state `0` to state `3` through `T`, you will face a reduction and normal state in one state.
To be honest, I didn't see that before. That's why I am asking.

Is this possible?
Shall I normally continue reducing? OR Am I wrong?

[image]

**Here is the Grammar in case of needing it:**

> E ---> E+T | T
>  T ---> T*F | F
>  F ---> (E) | id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no lookahead information, this is a shift/reduce conflict because the parser can't tell whether it should shift (follow the GOTO information) or reduce. This grammar, therefore, wouldn't be LR(0). If you have additional context about when to perform the reduction (perhaps if you're using an SLR(1), LALR(1), or LR(1) parser), then it's okay to have both a shift and a reduce in a state as long as the shift and the reduce aren't on the same terminal symbol.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, Thank you. The problem is this is two times our lecturer brings us this kind question without giving us any *additional context about when to perform  the reduction* as you said.

Comment: However, today the same question came in the final exam and I solved it using NDFA. That means `state 1` goes to `2` states through `T`.